# Why my NSMutableDictionary is getting null in setObject?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am trying this code,

```
 NSString *titleOfPlace = [place objectForKey:@"name"];
 NSString *reference = [place objectForKey:@"reference"];
 [placesExtraInfo setObject:reference forKey:titleOfPlace];
 NSLog(@"%@", (NSString *)[placesExtraInfo objectForKey:titleOfPlace]);
```

Output is,

```
2011-11-21 10:06:49.536 Tittle-Tattle[25545:1bb03] 0
2011-11-21 10:06:49.554 Tittle-Tattle[25545:1bb03] (null)
2011-11-21 10:06:49.555 Tittle-Tattle[25545:1bb03] (null)
2011-11-21 10:06:49.555 Tittle-Tattle[25545:1bb03] (null)
2011-11-21 10:06:49.555 Tittle-Tattle[25545:1bb03] (null)
.... about 20 of them as I had 20 objects to add...
```

What am I doing wrong?

**PS** When I NSlog value of `titleOfPlace` and `reference` than it prints of perfect. Than why it is not getting saved inside NSMutableDictionary?

Thanks for any input given!

**UPDATE**

```
title John's Grill
reference CnRkAAAAmyHKGYtr9brX5uJEwlyK791oCWErzrY8hKjFX2eXBV5hrrbVjE_-CPvCfoxUpu4TiXswTXUtvP_UkYG2p4RG2a1oc_4HSxku1jIlVx0H4LZgo_SQbUMSrJ1xDvwxxWVsyWtEjxCIF6qma_slsFSLphIQmSnwBgYQATX46MXkuW0s5BoUGM0K_KRvH_gbc4k-TSsSpgnQyTk
please no null (null)
2011-11-21 10:19:40.339 Tittle-Tattle[30277:1bb03] title Fifth Floor
reference CnRiAAAAtzTFHqqcAMyYzuKSq7nwHdt9e-lnP1W4i6pyUGQiomT0SvqDm1RWxhH05fJpqMJ9RdU8QHO-g7-EXgVHQnoms_bip5gGXdE96SCN7HQW5-Y69K7144VvgnOATVVNZRWQgyNZ2NNYRSltVuL61UXg7BIQ8YinfdZ6Ahq2lU6XhNVQ7hoU2IwUAHKcGHELPeYgbshPmiS9nOA
please no null (null)
2011-11-21 10:19:40.339 Tittle-Tattle[30277:1bb03] title Ghirardelli Chocolate
reference CnRsAAAAkHnx_nYhhe4QnV2jQyWdU5Vb387rFdVlhPcsnp6ZUjEroEzRLCcYO687ybSlTqSMDP5BxJVeehgUt9kkL97l1puos89e2HT85t-H5VWl7G0qZ0M_IoL0Gp3VmKl07MQRFt0_zdXesSVjSzLFRpBDChIQwcpeapYjGYq8jSQTZUmoMxoUSS1M0rBvMkqKSRRGMpWlyWbHUJ0
please no null (null)
```

Comment: Make sure `placesExtraInfo` is **not** `nil`.

Comment: @Maudicus , Hey mate! see my question, it's still null :(

Comment: I figured, that's why I ended up deleting my comment before you could respond.

Comment: @albertamg , You are 100% right! thanks buds! could you please write this as an answer as you deserve an upvote and accept points :)! Thanks

Comment: @Brogrammer You are welcome! I'll do it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, make sure `placesExtraInfo` is **not** `nil` (If you send `objectForKey:` to `nil`, it will return `nil`).

Answer (score 2):

I think albertamg is right — check `placesExtraInfo`. Your question only says that you've checked `titleOfPlace` and `reference`. Trying to store a `nil` object into a dictionary would raise an exception, but messaging anything to `nil` results in `nil`.

Comment: +1 - thanks for the mention. I provided an answer upon request by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

albertamg is on to something.

You cannot set a nil value and cannot set a non-nil value to a nil key

```
//given
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
//will crash here
[dict setObject:nil forKey:@"key"];
//will crash here if the above line is commented out
[dict setObject:@"val" forKey:nil];
```

However,

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [nil objectForKey:@"key"]);
```

outputs

```
2011-11-20 18:22:08.609 TestEnvironment[1221:207] (null)
```

Comment: Yeah! I figured that out, Java knowledge is killing me! can't think of memory allocation :( I will get there :)

Comment: +1 - thanks for the mention. I provided an answer upon request by the OP.

Comment: No problem.  +1 for you.  Your comment was first and solved his problem. (We can assume Brogrammer is he? Can't we?)

Comment: @Maudicus Thanks for the +1. (I think you can use the [singular they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) in this context).